# elFinder How to get protocol name

Tags: javascript, elfinder

I open elFinder in popup window and i got files in this callback:

```
getFileCallback: function (file) {
 var w = window.opener || window.parent || window;
     w.postMessage && w.postMessage(JSON.stringify(file), '*');
     $('#elfinder').remove();          
},
```

Is it possible to get source protocol each of file:
dropbox, gdrive, ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using official PHP volume drivers.

```
getFileCallback: function (file) {
 var w = window.opener || window.parent || window;
     var drivers = {
        bd: 'Box',
        db: 'Dropbox',
        f:  'FTP',
        gd: 'GoogleDrive',
        l:  'LocalFileSystem',
        od: 'OneDrive',
     }, m;
     if (m = file.hash.match(/^(bd|db|f|gd|l|od)/)) {
        file.driver = drivers[m[1]];
     }
     w.postMessage && w.postMessage(JSON.stringify(file), '*');
     $('#elfinder').remove();          
},
```

Please check `file.driver`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works for me.
Also it would be cool to get in this place shared link for this file if it has mime == "directory".
Is it possible?

Comment: just one fix: 
file is array in this case.

Comment: Please check an option of the command `getfile`. https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/master/js/elFinder.options.js#L249-L262